# KBTouch Radius is log whenever typing on keyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I'm pretty new to obj-c so forgive me if this is a stupid question as I've searched and couldn't find anything of use... anytime i type on a keyboard, my log window is bombarded with the message below. what does it mean and how do i keep it out of my log window?

> KBTouch Radius:  phase: Ended tap count: 12 window: > view: ; layer = > location in window: {385.49993374943551, 634.99991819264267} previous location in window: {385.49993374943551, 634.99991819264267} location in view: {379.99993374943551, 105.49991819264267} previous location in view: {379.99993374943551, 105.49991819264267}

Comment: You'll have to share much more information to get any help on this for instance, what is KBTouch? Is that a custom class you created? Is there an NSLog in some touch event method in that class that would explain where that output is originating from?

Comment: kbtouch isn't something i created.  i get this issue with a fresh project and a textfield using LRSmartTextField. kbtouch isn't in LRSmartTextField either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your devices had jailbreak and had installed the plugin UniversalForce?
Uninstall this plugin and try again.

Comment: wow never would have guess it was the results of a jailbreak tweak. thanks